# Creating Duplicate Excel Row based the values in another Excel file cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have  two Excel Files `Excel File 1` and `Excel File 2`
I want to create Bill of Material to import into one of my Applications. I have components listed in the same row. I want to create duplicate Rows like if Part Number have 3 Components i want duplicate the same row 3 times and change the `lineNbr`and `PartId` fields of `Excel File 2`

`Excel File 1`
[image: Source]

`Excel File 2`

[image]

I want to update `Excel File 2` as shown below in the same Sheet. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question comes in three parts.

1. restructuring the data in file 1
2. Using VLOOKUP to get the data from file 2 and put it into your restuctured data  (this is different to how you were thinking about it).
3. adding the line number column.

Solving 2 is not to bad - find out how vlookup works if you don't know.

Solving 3 is easy once you have the data restructured.  You simply add a formula to the line number column that uses an IF statement to see if the value in the bomitem column in the same row is different to the one in the bomitem column in the row above.  If it is add one to the value in the cell in the row above the forumla column (ie the line number column) , if not use 1.

Solving 1. Is harder.  There is no majic button for this in excel.  I suspect the easiest way will be to copy and paste!  I say this as you are probably only going to do this once, and there are probably not many BOM PN columns.

If either of these statements are not true, you might want to consider writing VBA.

You could also write formulas to do it.

I've run out of time.